# Casting floating point (double) to string

Tags: c++, boost

I'm running into something I've never seen before and would very much like to understand what is going on. I'm trying to round a double to 2 decimal places and cast that value to a string. Upon completion of the cast things go crazy on me.

Here is the code:

```
void formatPercent(std::string& percent, const std::string& value, Config& config)
{
    double number = boost::lexical_cast<double>(value);
    if (config.total == 0)
    {
        std::ostringstream err;
        err << "Cannot calculate percent from zero total.";
        throw std::runtime_error(err.str());
    }
    number = (number/config.total)*100;
    // Format the string to only return 2 decimals of precision
    number = floor(number*100 + .5)/100;
    percent = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(number);

    return;
}
```

I wasn't getting quite what I expected so I did some investigation. I did the following:

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << "number = " << number << std::endl;
std::cout << "percent = " << percent << std::endl;
```

...and get the following:

```
number = 30.63
percent = 30.629999999999999
```

I suspect that boost is doing something funny. Does anyone have any insight here?

Seriously, how strange is this?!? I ask for 10 digit precision on a double and get 4 digits. I ask to cast those 4 digits to a string and get that mess. What is going on?

Comment: Is it time for another link to What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Your link doesn't address my question at all.  It's actually just a pedantic way of getting around answering my question.  You will notice the answer from Martin Beckett directly answered this question.

Comment: The expansion of 30.63 in binary is infinite just as the expansion of 1/3 in base 10 is infinite. lexical-cast<std::string>() does what it is supposed to because number really isn't 30.63. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016464/boostlexical-cast-conversion-double-to-string-c

Comment: @Apprentice - but the binary representation to 10sf is still 0.6300000000, unless you knew the quirks of setprecision() you would expect it to print this.

Comment: @Beckett, the question was why setprecision() worked and percent did not. What was unexpected to Rico wasn't setprecision() but percent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

std::precision sets the maximum number of significant digits to display

> On the default floating-point
>   notation, the precision field
>   specifies the maximum number of
>   meaningful digits to display in total
>   counting both those before and those
>   after the decimal point. Notice that
>   it is not a minimum and therefore it
>   does not pad the displayed number with
>   trailing zeros if the number can be
>   displayed with less digits than the
>   precision.

30.629999999999999 is the actually floating point representation of 30.63

Comment: Thank you for this helpful answer.  I did not realize std::precision would not show trailing zeros (or 9s).

Answer (score 3):

The decimal number `30.63` cannot be stored in an object of type double. The closest valid double value, the one that is actually stored, is `8621578536647393 * 2^-48`, which, in decimal notaion, is `30.629999999999999005240169935859739780426025390625`.

You can see that if you do `std::cout << std::setprecision(100) << "number = " << number << std::endl;`

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for ten digits of precision, but the actual "inaccuracy" is further down, so when it's rounded into ten digits it becomes a neat 30.63. Your lexical_cast takes all the digits into account, therefore resulting in the precise floating point value (perhaps not the kind of precision you want, but it's the most precise representation of what's in the computer's memory).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that floating point numbers cannot accurately represent arbitrary decimal values.  What you're seeing is floating point error.  Boost is accurately displaying the value you provide to it.