# C++ function call order (boost) - confused

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, boost, rounding

I've got a small C++ problem. First of all, "my" language is Java, so I'm new to C++.
I have this function:

```
double readableDouble( double input )
{
    return   (int)(input*100+0.5)/100.0;
}
```

As you can see, nothing special. Now I call the function from another function (in the same class):

```
        cout << readableDouble(4434.21121131234323243) <<endl; // result: 4434.22 all okay
        cout << readableDouble(tempTrack.getLenght()/1000.0); // result: 30.56 all okay
        string lenght = boost::lexical_cast<string>(readableDouble((tempTrack.getLenght()/1000.0))); // result 30.55999999999982. expected: 30.56
```

getLenght() returns a double. (same double for both calls)

I am not quite sure how this is happening?

.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: Oh, it should be 30.56 as well.

Comment: Maybe you will find [this](http://floating-point-gui.de/) useful

Comment: Not relevant to your problem, but it's spelt 'length'.

Comment: Thanks (as you may noticed I'm not a native speaker) ;) - year, but there should be no rounding issues. the only difference between the both examples is the call of lexical_cast

Comment: Your `cout` output depends on the precision you have set for `cout`. If you set it high enough, you'll get the same output as `boost::lexical_cast` gives you.

Comment: Then how to format the String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016464/boostlexical-cast-conversion-double-to-string-c) (Credit to [Mic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/35656/mic)):

> From the documentation for [boost lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm):
>
> For more involved conversions, such as where precision or formatting
>   need tighter control than is offered by the default behavior of
>   lexical_cast, the conventional stringstream approach is recommended.
>   Where the conversions are numeric to numeric, numeric_cast may offer
>   more reasonable behavior than lexical_cast.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> #include <sstream>
>
>     #include <iomanip>
>
>     int main() {
>         std::ostringstream ss;
>         double x = 5;
>         ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2);
>         ss << x;
>         std::string s = ss.str();
>         return 0;
>     }
> ```